# Limit users to edit only certain pages or exclude pages for them?

Tags: access-rights, impresspages

I just started to look around in IP4 - looks great! As usual, in these situations I will ask some stupid questions from time to time. :-)

Here is my first: Is there a way to limit editors to certain pages or exclude certain pages from editing by non-superusers?

Answer (score 0):

By default - no. But you can create a plugin that gives you such granular permissions.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! 
I'll probably have to get deeper into this subject what will take time. My coding skills are not so good ;-)